# Error with RDLC report on deployed machine

Tags: c#, windows, rdlc

I have application deployed on windows 7 OS. Installed app is having rdlc reports but when I open the form containing report viewer it throws below error but if I debug the application then it works properly.

Error Thrown:

[image]

I have later installed Microsoft System clr types and Micosoft Report Viewer but even the issue is not resolved. Can anybody please help me.

Comment: this looks like the problem was in user code. I would not have thought on missing runtime dependencies as those usually manifest in different exceptions. can you get a debug build with a PDB running in the target environment, so you get a line number? and show what is in `TestReport_Load`?

Comment: using debug build I got line number where it was failing, the error was regarding string_Split function of SQL server. There was SQL Server 2008 r2 on Client system which does not support for String_Split hence changed that function to user defined and the issue is resolved. Thanks dlatikay for your support.